# How can I combine these two interfaces of objectss into one?

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, react-typescript

I don't see a point using two TypeScript interfaces for this JSON response:

```
{
  "branchesArray": [
    {
      "code": "",
      "branchName": " ",
      "city": "",
      "address": ""
    },
    {
      "code": "",
      "branchName": "",
      "city": "",
      "address": ""
    }
]}
```

Is there a way to combine them together?

```
interface DigestAuthSuccess {
    branchesArray: BranchesArray[];
}
interface BranchesArray {
    code: string;
    branchName: string;
    city: string;
    address: string;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Note: In the two interfaces you already have, the `BranchesArray` type is misnamed. It's not the type of an array of branches, it's the type of a single branch.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need DigestAuthSuccess interface when you can type an branch as an array aswell.

```
interface Branch {
    code: string;
    branchName: string;
    city: string;
    address: string;
}


function foo(branchArr: Branch[]){
  console.log(branchArr)
  return branchArr
}

foo([{
      code: "aaa",
      branchName: "bbb",
      city: "ccc",
      address: 'ddd'
    }])
```